# grammar LL(1) conflicts

Tags: compilation, compiler-warnings, formal-languages

Hello I don't understand why there is a conflict in the assgnStmt production. I'm using coco/R and I get "LL1 warning in assgnStmt: ID is start & successor of deletable structure".
Thank you.

```
 COMPILER program

 CHARACTERS
 Letter= 'a'..'z'.
 Digit= '0'..'9'.

 TOKENS
 NUM= Digit {Digit}.
 ID= Letter {Letter}.

 PRODUCTIONS  
 program
   = stmts
   .
  stmts = assgnStmt { assgnStmt ';' } .

  assgnStmt
     = {ID "==" }  expr
  .
  expr = term { ('+' | '-') term } .

  term = factor { ( '*' | '/'  ) factor  } .

  factor
     = '(' expr ')'
     | ID
     | NUM
     .
  END program.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ID "=="}` is a "deletable structure", which is a way of saying that it is optional. It can start with `ID`, obviously. But `expr` can also start with `ID`, and if `{ID "=="}` is not present, the parser must try to recognise an `expr`.

LL parsers always need to know what production they are trying to recognise. But when the parser encounters an `ID` in this context, it cannot tell whether to expect `{ID "=="}` or `expr`.

That is what the error message means. Fixing it is trickier, although not impossible. You could start by trying something like `ID {"==" ID} rest-of-expr` but that will only recognise some assignments (precisely the ones where `expr` does start with `ID`).

(This is an example of why I don't find LL(1) parser generators very satisfactory. An LR(1) parser would have no problems with that syntax. So I don't know enough about Coco/R to provide more suggestions.)

Comment: I added < expr { "==" expr } >, that is more general , leaving the semantic analysis do the right job.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that option. Anyway, I hope the answer helped a bit.